# servlet web.xml mapping

Tags: servlets, mapping, web.xml

> I am working on simple web application using Servlet & Jsp. But i have
>   one problem where i am working on web.xml. Can i use same url pattern
>   for many servlet class for example

code from jsp page

```
<form action="Answer" method="get">
                    <input id="foo" type="text" name="question"/> 
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />  
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Back"/>
                </form>
```

Code from web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Answer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>RemoveAbbr</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Answer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Answer</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Answer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Preprocess</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Answer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Answer</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> So, My question is what are true conditions from below options  1) if
>   i click on Submit button can it map to RemoveAbbr 2)  if i click on
>   Back button can it map to Preprocess 3) creates conflict because same
>   url pattern(Form Action from jsp) can not used for different servlet
>   class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `<servlet>` needs to have a unique `<servlet-name>`, so you will need to rename one. Also, the `<url-pattern>`'s should be different so the servlet container will know how to handle the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a unique `<servlet-name>`. For example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SecondServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.SecondServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/first.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SecondServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/second.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Check this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dW%20CloudOE%20content-_-j-hangman-app-_-article), there I found an example to edit web.xml file and add the servlets. Also the source code is available, so it was useful for me.